# How to dynamically pass a user to "EXECUTE AS USER" from a cursor in SQL-Transact?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to execute a stored procedure (first_procedure) using `WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER` with different users. In order to do so, I created a table with valid usernames and I try to execute a second procedure that calls the first one using the `EXECUTE AS USER` statement.

My second procedure looks like:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @LOGIN nvarchar(MAX);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for
        SELECT USERNAME FROM [dbo].[SIM_TABLE] WHERE USERNAME LIKE 'DIJON%';
    OPEN cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @LOGIN;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            PRINT @LOGIN;
            EXECUTE AS USER = @LOGIN;
            EXEC dbo.first_procedure; 
            REVERT;
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @LOGIN;
        END;
    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur
END
```

The issue that I am facing is that I really don't know how to format the `@LOGIN` part after `EXECUTE AS USER =` in order to be valid. When I affect a string to `@LOGIN` it's working, but from the cursor it won't. Is there some transformation needed?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this section of the documentation for `EXECUTE AS` here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms181362.aspx#_user - You'll see it says:

> The user or login name specified in EXECUTE AS  must exist as a principal in sys.database_principals or sys.server_principals

That means that (as well as actually being a principal - i.e. a login) it must be formatted the same.

So for a SQL login that would simply be `username`, and for a Windows login that would be `DomainName\username`.

You can get a list of your database principals as follows:

```
SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals
```

**Update**

So it turns out that it was the nvarchar(MAX) datatype of your @LOGIN variable that the `EXECUTE AS` statement was objecting to. It's not the nvarchar itself that's the problem, it's the (MAX). This is not entirely surprising, as the (MAX) datatypes work very differently from the fixed-size versions.

Let's try a couple of examples:

```
DECLARE @LOGIN nvarchar(MAX)
SET @LOGIN = N'MyUser'
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @LOGIN
```

> Msg 15533, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>
> Invalid data type is supplied in the 'Execute As' statement.

And with nvarchar(256):

```
DECLARE @LOGIN nvarchar(256)
SET @LOGIN = N'MyUser'
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @LOGIN
```

> Command(s) completed successfully.

Actually, I would recommend using the `sysname` type, as that is what SQL server uses internally for object names - although that is only a user defined type for a non-nullable nvarchar(256), in SQL 2008 R2 onwards at least.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. The USERNAME in my table are current SQL logins.

Comment: OK cool. According to the docs usernames have to be formatted the same as the principal. Are they, and does it still not work?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer because your comment below (in the next answer) says that the user names in your table are current SQL logins.  In that case, instead of using "EXECUTE AS USER", you should probably be using "EXECUTE AS LOGIN".  You also might want to get rid of the cursor:

```
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   DECLARE @LOGIN nvarchar(MAX)

   SET @LOGIN = ''

   WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN

     SELECT TOP 1 @LOGIN = USERNAME
     FROM   [dbo].[SIM_TABLE]
     WHERE  USERNAME LIKE 'DIJON%' AND USERNAME > @LOGIN
     ORDER  BY USERNAME ASC

     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BREAK

     EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @LOGIN
     EXEC dbo.first_procedure 
     REVERT

   END
END
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the cursor is an issue because the `PRINT @LOGIN` statement is working. It's only the `EXECUTE AS USER = @LOGIN` that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation, the solution is to cast the @LOGIN...

```
EXECUTE AS USER = CAST(@LOGIN AS VARCHAR);
```

I'm not sure why the `NVARCHAR` is not working in this case, but casting in `VARCHAR` do the job.

Comment: It's because it doesn't like the (MAX), not the `nvarchar` itself. Please see my updated answer for more info. Surely you don't need (MAX) for your usernames!? The `sysname` type would be best here anyway...